# Undesired dragging when scrolling

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-ui, html

I've been using Jquery ui.Draggable.
And when I'm scrolling the paragraph the div is draging at the same time as its parent element.
Could anybody help me with How to temporarily disable dragging while scrolling?

```
<div class="note">
        <p>
        Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing 
        and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the 
        industry's standard dummy text ever since the 1500s, 
        when an unknown printer took a galley of type and 
        scrambled it to make a type specimen book. It has 
        survived not only five centuries, but also the leap 
        into electronic typesetting, remaining essentially 
        unchanged. It was popularised in the 1960s with the 
        release of Letraset sheets containing Lorem Ipsum passages, 
        and more recently with desktop publishing software like Aldus 
        PageMaker including versions of Lorem Ipsum.
        </p>
</div>



$(function(){
            var str = "div.note";
            var el = $(str);
            var er = $(str+' p');
            $this = er;

            el.draggable().resizable();

            el.bind('resize', function(){
             var node = $(this);
             var size = Math.pow(node.width(),2) + Math.pow(node.height(),2);
             size = Math.sqrt(size);
             node.css({'font-size':(size/2)+'%', 'padding':(size/24)+'px'});
            });     
});
```

Best Regards

Comment: I tried your example on JsFiddle and I can't see what the problem is: http://jsfiddle.net/s65UR/

Can you make one so we can try it?

Comment: You've got the problem in your example. Grab the scroling line and instead of scrolling you are dragging with buggy scroll! Here it is, with a bigger div it's easier to notice http://jsfiddle.net/s65UR/1/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can set a handle:

http://jqueryui.com/demos/draggable/#option-handle

```
...

    el.draggable({handle: 'p'}).resizable();

...
```

here in jsFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/s65UR/2/